# Getting value of template parameter from embracing type

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Say, I have a template class with an integer parameter:

```
template <int N>
class A
{
public:
    static int get_N()
    {
        return N;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        cout << "N = " << T::get_N() << endl; // Accessing N via the auxiliary method
    }
};
```

To reference the N template parameter in class B I had to create an auxiliary method in A. I would like to do something like this:

```
template <int N>
class A
{
};

template<typename T>
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        cout << "N = " << T::N << endl; // Accessing N directly
    }
};
```

The problem is that I'm going to have a lot of A template specializations and I don't really want to copy this auxiliary method to all of specialized classes and i don't want to introduce inheritance for this.
Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: Why not use static constant for this purpose: `static const int N_ = N;`?

Comment: @Constructor Static constant is the same as static function in this respect. If I were to create a specialized class `template <> class A<1> {};` I would have to copy this constant along.

Answer (score 5):

You could deduce the value from a specialization:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> struct get_N;
template <template <int N> class T, int N>
struct get_N<T<N>> {
    static constexpr int value = N;
};

template <int N> struct A {};

template <typename T>
struct B {
    void f() { std::cout << get_N<T>::value << '\n'; }
};

int main() {
    B<A<10>>().f();
}
```

Comment: +1 its funny what a high percentage of ansers I like come from a handfull of people here at SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract `N` like this:

```
template<typename A>
struct get_N;

template<int N>
struct get_N<A<N> > : std::integral_constant<int,N> { };
```

This way you don't need to define anything within each `A` specialization, yet you can say e.g.

```
using X = A<3>;
cout << "N = " << get_N<X>() << endl;  // prints: N = 3
```

However, I might still prefer to let `A` derive a lightweight template class that only defines a `static constrexpr` variable as in juanchopanza's answer. Then each `A` specialization would look like

```
template<>
struct A<3> : A_base<3> { ... };
```

which is not too bad. In fact, looking at both options again, I see that `A_base` is nothing more than

```
template<int N>
using A_base = std::integral_constant<int,N>;
```

so it could be given a more generic short name. I usually call it `num`.